# Angular drag and drop event is not working `drop` event is not firing

Tags: typescript, drag-and-drop, angular7

A piece of code is misbehaving, I don't know what has changed lately, but part of it not working.
HTML

```
<div class="projectList_main" *ngIf="testCaseSec">
  <div class="backgroundColor" *ngIf="!testCaseDetail">
    <div class="backgroundinner">
      <p class="draganddrop">DRAG AND DROP HERE</p>
      <div class="row paddingrow">
        <div class="col-md-6 borderright" (drop)="onDrop1($event);" (dragover)="onDragOver($event)"  >
          <img src="./assets/images/existingplan.png" class="existingplanimg"/>
          <p class="add">ADD TO EXISTING SCENARIO</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" (dragover)="onDragOverCreate($event)" (drop)="onDropCreate($event);" >
          <img src="./assets/images/createplan.png" class="createplanimg" />
          <p class="add">CREATE NEW SCENARIO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: mage]

as you can see in console `onDragOver($event)` works fine where as `onDrop1($event);` dosen't.
And it also shows stop cursor pointer on that point only but that place should be droppable.
In second case right side It works fine on drop also.

Comment: Please share a (stackblitz) minimal reproducible example. We need to see the .ts files, not just .html

Comment: Hi Joe tried to do in stackbllitz but not able to handle one part dependency
It automatically upgrades my  dependency to "primeng": "^9.1.3" from "primeng": "^7.1.3"
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-form-login-angular-tutorial-qna9ww?file=package.json

Comment: Try installing it with `primeng@7.1.3`

Comment: done but it is still minimalist try dragging near checkbox
on first place, it shows stop cursor
In the second place, it shows droppable.
And drop1() function doesn't fire up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to adhere to the `ondragover` <-> `ondrop` [convention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API#Define_a_drop_zone).

What this practically means for your stackblitz example is these 3 added lines in `login.component.ts`:

```
...
onDragOver(ev: any) {
    ev.stopPropagation();        // <---
    ev.preventDefault();         // <---
    console.log("onDragOver");
...

onDrop1(ev: any) {
    ev.preventDefault();      // <---
    console.log(
      "cDrop Create",
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Mind awarding the bounty too? :)